# Cannot access Kaa Sandbox SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, kaa

I wanted to ssh into Kaa's sandbox using `ssh kaa@127.0.0.1 -p 2222` given in the virtual machine to us and also in one of the Data Collection demo where it said that we need to ssh into kaa's sandbox then we can see our mongoDB using our application token of our demo to see data saved into it.

But we do know the password is `kaa123`. But I tried 4 times, it shows `permission denied, please try again` until it shows `permission denied (publickey,password)`.

ThusIi would like to seek help. I haven set up anything apart from downloading `cmake`, `gcc`. I changed the port on Raspberry pi to port 2222. Raspberry pi is connected to my computer using an Ethernet cable.

- Raspberry pi static ip address : `169.254.220.68`
- Computer static ip address : `169.254.220.135`
- Kaa's sandbox ssh address is : `ssh kaa@127.0.0.1 -p 222`

Your answers are really very very important to us as we have been stuck for days for our mini Final Year Project.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, the situation is next:

1. Kaa Sandbox is running in VirtualBox image on host 169.254.220.135
2. Raspberry Pi has IP address 169.254.220.68
3. You tries to get to Kaa Sandbox by ssh from Raspberry Pi
4. Kaa Sandbox shows in terminal that you can access its SSH via localhost (127.0.0.1) port 2222

If that is correct, the technical details are as follows:

1. You should be able (if you didn't change Kaa Sandbox configuration) to access the Kaa Sandbox **from your VirtualBox host** just as it is shown in the Kaa Sandbox terminal:

   ```
   ssh kaa@localhost -p 2222
   ```

Please try this first. Should this fail you will not be able to pass the further checks below.

2. The Kaa Sandbox is shiped with NAT networking mode configuration. This means (among other things) that its internal IP addresse(s) (including 10.0.2.15) cannot be reached from outside. That is, you cannot connect to this address from Raspberry Pi and even from your VirtualBox host. NAT hides them under the VirtualBox host IP address.
3. To enable access to the Kaa Sandbox from outside we pre-configured the Kaa Sandbox VirtualBox image to forward several ports from your host IP address to the internal IP address (10.0.2.15) which is under NAT. The port forwarding configuration is next:

   ```
   ${HostIP}:2222 -> 10.0.2.15:22
   ```

This means that all the connections to ${HostIP}:2222 will be forwarded to the Kaa Sandbox's 10.0.2.15:22.

Thus:

1. You should be able to get Kaa Sandbox SSH **locally** by kaa@localhost -p 2222 **and** by host IP: kaa@169.254.220.135 -p 2222
2. You need to use your host IP from **remote**: kaa@169.254.220.135 -p 2222

Please let me know if something is unclear here or does not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 always points to your own computer. If kaa's sanbox is in your Raspberry Pi, try `ssh kaa@169.254.220.68 -p 2222`

Comment: Thanks ! But i am supposed to SSH to Kaa's sandbox from my raspberry pi. Shouldnt i type the address given on the kaa's sandbox login page?

Comment: What is the IP of Kaa's sandbox? Is it a separate device?

Comment: SSH TO VM : ssh kaa@127.0.0.1 -p 2222               , its a sandbox

Comment: Can you try running ifconfig or ip link commands within Kaa's sandbox?

Comment: This is my first time with kaa..... thus i dont know . but the previous line i sent , it is shown on the virtualbox where i ran my sandbox instance. One of the instruction is : Now you need to replace %your_sandbox_instance_ip/host% with the actual host/ip address of your Sandbox. To do this, go to the Sandbox Management page and specify the real IP of your machine in the Kaahost/IP block. Alternatively, you can use the following command: $ ssh kaa@127.0.0.1 -p 2222.

Comment: Try "ip neighbor" from the raspberry pi. I mean outside the VM, in a terminal and paste the output here.

Comment: Actually i realised , i can use ''ifconfig'' inside the Kaa sandbox to find out ip addresses. There are 2 given ones , one is eth0 and the other is  Lo

Comment: The connection timed out. the ethernet address is 10.0.2.15

Comment: I think I was getting it wrong. Is kaa in a VM inside the Pi or a different computer? If it is in a different computer does the ssh command work from that computer?

Comment: Kaa is inside a VM which is in a different computer. It is not inside the raspberry pi. however , if we implement commands . we use putty to connect to rpi to set up a terminal to type our commands there. And no , for the ssh commands , it does not work on both my computer's putty which is connected to the raspberry pi and it does not work on the raspberrypi's terminal too. Sorry , i am not that technical into these data comm.

Comment: Connect the putty to 10.0.2.15.

Comment: The instruction to ssh to the kaa's sandbox is : You can access the collected data directly from the database using the MongoDB CLI tool. To do this, access Sandbox virtual machine over ssh using the username kaa and password kaa123 or use the virtual machine to run a Mongo client application for the MongoDB database.Now you need to replace %your_sandbox_instance_ip/host% with the actual host/ip address of your Sandbox. To do this, go to the Sandbox Management page and specify the real IP of your machine in the Kaahost/IP block. Alternatively, you cantry: $ ssh kaa@127.0.0.1 -p 2222.

Comment: Did you specify the real ip of your machine in the Sandbox Management page?

Comment: I put it as 10.0.2.15

Comment: No. Put is as 169.254.220.135

Comment: so i continue to ssh to kaa's sandbox using the raspberrypi ?(:

Comment: ssh kaa@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 , it then asked us for password. But same thing , permission denied thrice and then lastly it says ''Permission denied(publickey,password.) Whereas i tried ssh kaa@10.0.2.15 -p 2222 , it says connection timed out ):

Comment: **Note**: That the '10.0.2.15' IP address visible from Kaa Sandbox's 'ifconfig' output is just the *virtual* IP address within the VirtualBox virtualization in NAT networking mode. This effectively means that you cannot reach (due to NAT technology nature) this IP address from outside of the VirtualBox.

So, the correct IP address would be either *localhost* (which is same as 127.0.0.1) - for access from the same PC host; or the *real IP address* of the PC host - this is available both locally and remotely.